# Laravel 5.5 migration error

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am trying to migrate my postgresql table, but when launch the command `php artisan migrate` it return the follow error:

> SQLSTATE[08P01]: <>: 7 ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000003" requires 2 (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>      where table_schema = migrations and table_name = ?)

One of my migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateSchedulesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schedules', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('schedule_name')->unique();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('launch_sequence_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('day_of_week', 10)->nullable();
        $table->string('command_type', 50);
        $table->integer('hours')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('minutes')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('dd')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('mm')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('yyyy')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->boolean('enabled')->default(1);
        $table->boolean('ascending')->default(0);
        $table->dateTime('last_execution')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('last_success')->nullable();
        $table->integer('retry')->default(0);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE schedules ADD CONSTRAINT day_of_week_check CHECK ((day_of_week)::text = ANY (ARRAY[(\'all\'::character varying)::text, (\'monday\'::character varying)::text, (\'tuesday\'::character varying)::text, (\'wednesday\'::character varying)::text, (\'thursday\'::character varying)::text, (\'friday\'::character varying)::text, (\'saturday\'::character varying)::text, (\'sunday\'::character varying)::text]))');
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('schedules');
}

}
```

And my database configuration:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
'connections' => [

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' =>  env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
        //'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ]
],
```

My .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=livion
DB_USERNAME=livion
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DB_SCHEMA=public
```

I tried to track it down and seems that it doesn't use the correct grammar for the function `repositoryExists`, it uses the default grammar witch doesn't send the schema parameter.

The other query executed via model or repository works fine, I get this error only for the migration command.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: post your migration code too

Comment: Have you checked your DB Driver in config file / dotenv file ? 
Like DB_CONNECTION=postgresql

Comment: I edit my post with my configuration

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: I am using PHP 7.1.11 on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Are all migrations failing with this error or just this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem.
I migrated the project from laravel 5.3 to 5.5 and the old project used the module Aejnsn\Postgresify.

It causes my problem on migration.

Remove it and all works again.